# Where is the configuration setting to show IP address on shell prompt being stored?

Tags: ssh

We have two Xservers on our network. On server A all our employees have an account setup, but on B the only account is the admin account. I can SSH to server A fine with my username and password that are set on that server as expected.

However, when I SSH to server B using the same user account I have setup on server A it lets me in. Upon login it sends me to the home account mounted at the network location (`/Network/Servers/server A/Users/pmilb`) and at the shell prompt it says

```
rrcs-111-111-111-111:~ pmilb$
```

where `111-111-111-111` is my external IP address.

I am the new system admin here and was poking around testing things out. I was just wondering why it does this and where is this configured? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That is set by the environment variable PS1.

`ps -p $$` Should tell you which shell is in use. If it says something other than bash then pretend I'm talking about that shell below.

Assuming you are in bash, this variable is set in /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc. If x-server stores this in a different place or changing it in those locations and reconnecting doesn't seem to have an affect check the man page with `man bash`, it should list the locations of configuration files for the shell.